# Error when trying to insert new data into sql databse in java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to insert new data in a SQL database using a DAO. I have a boolean method for insert but there is a SQL error or database is missing. Database is not missing because I tested it and it displays everything from the table.

Here is the connection method

```
public Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:studentdb.sqlite";
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
}
```

And the insert method

```
public boolean insertStu(Student stu) throws SQLException {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    boolean b = false;
    try {
        String query = "insert into studentdb (Name, Gender, DOB, Address, Postcode, StudentNumber, CourseTitle, StartDate, Bursary, Email) values (\""
                + stu.getName() + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getGender() + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getDob() + "\"," + "\""
                + stu.getAddress() + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getPostcode() + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getStudentNumber()
                + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getCourseTitle() + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getStartDate() + "\"," + "\""
                + stu.getBursary() + "\"," + "\"" + stu.getEmail() + "\")";

        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        b = statement.execute(query);
    } catch (SQLException s) {
        throw new SQLException("Contact Not Added");
    } finally {
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (resultset != null){
            resultset.close();
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

I have tried the SQL query in different program where the connection method was `Statement` type and the insert method was still `boolean` but now the requirement is to use `Connection` class. Either way it should work but I don't understand way is not working. The `Student` object has `get` and `set` methods for its variables.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please use a `PreparedStatement` instead of string concatenation

Comment: *How* did you test the sqlite file? Where is it located? Can you give the full path to it on disk in your connection string?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace of the error, don't make us guess.